# implementing Database-functionality objects in an N-Tier architecture?

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns

I'm adding functionality to our website which performs long-running processes asynchronously using MSMQ. Doing this ansynch, however means we need to notify users when their requests are completed. Using the command pattern, I created an interface* called INotify and composed that into the message class, so the message processing class can simply call GiveNotice() on the message's INotify object. The first implementation, EmailNotify, was more difficult than expected, as I was surprised to discover MailMessage isn't serializable, but got it going.

Now I'm working on a new concrete notifier, DBNotify, which will call a SP of some sort and update a status in the main transactional database. I'm tripped up in that I would like to reuse the DAL architecture we've already created, but INotify is a member of the Model project, which is more fundamental than the DAL.

Our hierarchy looks like this:
Common > Model > DAL > BAL

Here's more detail about the tiers. Bear in mind, I inherited this from :
Common is responsible for all "utility" functions which are used many places in the application, things like accessing configuration settings, parsing strings, non-business related functionality.

Model are business objects, what some folks call data transfer objects, collections of getters and setters. I've added some "smarts" at this layer, but only business rules internal to that object, such as "An item's name must begin with an alphanumeric character."

DAL is the data access layer, in theory, all that happens here is  model objects are moved into and out of the database.

BAL is the Business layer; in theory, business rules that govern the interaction of objects are enforced (i.e. "A form must have at least two items.").

So the INotify interface is defined an abstraction to allow the method of notification to vary independently (i.e. email, TXT, twitter, etc). It's fundamental to the system, so I have created it at the Model tier, which is independent of the DAL tier. However, I am creating a new concrete implementation of INotify whose notification method is to call a SP in a database.

Has anyone else dealt with a business object whose purpose is to interact with a database, and how do you situate that in your N-tier architecture?

Before you tell me to use Linq to Sql, great thanks. This is not a technical question (how do I do this), it's a design question (how should I do this).

I think there is a StackExchange site more focused on these sorts of language-independant design questions, so I'm going to copy this there.

Comment: * Interface in name only, since I actually want to serialize these objects, I had to make it an abstract class.

Comment: I am confused about your hierarchy. What are the Model and the BAL responsible for? I took BAL to stand for Business Access Layer but  then the Model seems out of place. In the code I have seen the Model is usually the most abstract and sits above (uses) or is part of the Business layer... Also, if the Model is more fundamental than the DAL, what is the problem with the DAL using classes from and calling methods on the Model?

Comment: Oh, and in case you didn't know, you do not need to add information in comments, you can simply edit your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input, there are several ideas here for improvements I plan to implement, although none directly answer the question I was asking.

I cross-posted this over to Programmers, where I think this sort of question may truly belong, and got some helpful ideas. If you're interested, the thread is here:
[Programmers thread on this issue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64196/dont-cross-the-streams-database-access-objects-independant-of-the-data-tier-in/64235). Admittedly, I added the "hint" of dependency injection based on my own research when I posted there, so the problem may have been clearer.

This is a great and helpful community, which I am so proud to participate in.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not really an answer to your question, but something to think about nonetheless.

I am at odds with where you put the data access in your component hierarchy. I would not put it between two functional domain layers. Not even "above" the single domain model classes. Data access, or persistency, is not a concern for any domain class. It should only be something that can be done to them, not something they do.

Even though I started out coding things like `TClient.Save` and `TClient.Load` I have now come to the conclusion that it is not the Client that decides it needs to be saved, but user interactions that dictate when a domain instance's data is needed and therefore should be loaded, and when an Client's data should be persisted, if at all. I am therefore now a proponent of coding (in the GUI, more specifically the controller's in the GUI) things like `DataStore.Load(ClientInstance)` and `DataStore.Save(ClientInstance)`. It is then up to the Data Access layer to figure out how to do that. It could use reflection in C#, or the new RTTI in Delphi to iterate over all the Client's properties so it can send them to a database.

While layering is a very good concept to separate concerns and keep you from putting stuff all over the place by simply adhering to "you can call down but not up", it does not help as much when addressing things like logging, exception handling, notifications and all those other interesting cross cutting concerns that every other component/layer needs.

In addition, the Common layer, as it is a utility layer should really be accessible to all other layers.

To put it all in a picture (where I have kept the distinction you make between simple domain classes, your model, and cross class business rules, your BAL):

```
+---+   +-------------+
| C |<--| Data Access |<--------------------------+
| o |   +-------------+                           |
| m |         |                                   |
| m |         |                                   |
| o |         v                                   |
| n |   +-------------+   +----------------+   +-----+
|   |<--| Model       +<--| Cross class    |<--| GUI |
|   |   +-------------+   | business rules |   |     |
|   |                     |                |   |     |
|   |<--------------------|                |   |     |
|   |                     +----------------+   |     |
|   |                                          |     |
|   |<-----------------------------------------|     |
+---+                                          +-----+
```

The INotify implementation that calls into the database is currently in the model, which in the picture above, does not call into the data access layer itself, it is only called, or rather interrogated, by the data access layer.

The question really is whether INotify should be in the "model", a part of the domain layer, or whether it should be a Common interface and there should be a separate "Notification" layer/component that is accessible from the domain and the GUI. This new component could not only concern itself with notifications, but many other cross cutting concerns, for example logging. It  has access to the common (of course) and data access components and to the GUI in at least in some sort of call back fashion.

In the picture below I have tried to visualize this, but I am not much good at visualization and always have problems with those pesky cross cutters. Thats why there are no call-arrows from the domain layer to the cross cutting concerns, though of course the domain layer should be able to access for example a "Logger" interface. Maybe I am trying to hard to distinguish between the common and the cross cutting components and an argument could be made to put these together, and visualize them as separate blocks within a "Utility" layer/component.

```
        +--------------------------------------------+
  +-----| Cross cutting concerns                     |
  |     +--------------------------------------------+
  v           v^                                    ^
+---+   +-------------+                             |
| C |<--| Data Access |<--------------------------+ |
| o |   +-------------+                           | |
| m |         |                                   | |
| m |         |                                   | |
| o |         v                                   | v
| n |   +-------------+   +----------------+   +-----+
|   |<--| Model       +<--| Cross class    |<--| GUI |
|   |   +-------------+   | business rules |   |     |
|   |                     |                |   |     |
|   |<--------------------|                |   |     |
|   |                     +----------------+   |     |
|   |                                          |     |
|   |<-----------------------------------------|     |
+---+                                          +-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because your `INotify` interface is in your Model layer doesn't mean all the concrete implementations need to be there. It SHOULD be an interface--the purpose of an interface is to achieve abstraction--not a base class--the purpose of a base class is to achieve shared functionality. So anywhere you have a property or parameter of this type throughout any of your layers, it should be declared as INotify. In your BAL (did you mean BLL, Business Logic Layer?) you would decide the concrete type to use for those instances of INotify. Depending on how complex your notifications are, you could define your concrete implementation in your BLL and have it use a helper class in the DAL to actually perform the call to your sproc, or you could define it as a class directly in your DAL since it interacts with the database; that's really a judgement call based on how much the class is responsible for; either way it should be accessible in the top layer.

> Has anyone else dealt with a business object whose purpose is to interact with a database, and how do you situate that in your N-tier architecture?

The way your projects are structured, it sounds like the logical responsibilities of each layer would be:

**Common:**
Shared utility methods with no dependencies on anything else in the project
**Model:**
Defines the structure of the entities in the system, also called DTO's or Data Transfer Objects, which means they can be transferred between layers. All they do is store your data and perform basic validation.
**DAL:**
Responsible for creating instances of classes from your Model layer and setting the properties based on values stored in a repository, such as a database. Also responsible for tracking changes to Model entities, and saving (persisting) those changes back to the repository.
**BAL/BLL:**
Uses the classes defined in the other layers to achieve something useful, and validates that the business requirements are followed.

You can achieve this with a variety of technologies and even using the same technology your exact implementation will vary depending on how you work. Something like Linq2Sql, or Entity Framework out of the box would blur the lines between your Model and your DAL; they want to define both in the same project. However, Entity Framework is more flexible and with some work you can split the definition of the entity model and the "context" (to use the Entity Framework term), which is ultimately responsible for the DAL component, into separate projects. You can edit the T4 templates or find ones online that will generate the entity and context class definitions from the entity model to support the Repository and Unit of Work design patterns, where you never reference an entity context directly but instead have it implement an IRepository interface, which makes your code more testable. I've never personally worked with NHibernate, but my understanding is that it's capable of doing the same thing (and arguably may currently do a better job).

Comment: nice effort, here is a suggestion though: Answers in SO tend to be short and to the point. Either try to shorten it or split it up in more paragraphs and add headings.

Comment: INotify is functionally an interface, but you can't serialize an interface, so I made it an abstract class. It limits the flexibility (if it were an interface, I could inherit from other classes and still implement INotify).

Comment: Yes, BAL == BLL. Just using the name I inherited.

Answer (score 1):

If your Model classes are your DTOs (what some might call data structures or data types), they should (probably) lay "across" your other layers and be known to all of them.

Based on what you say, you might have a MessageProcessing class that sits in the BAL and receives messages from other parts of the BAL or the DAL, then notifies anyone who is listening (the UI or other interested members of the BAL).

Comment: The messages go into MSMQ and are processed by code running as a service, so creating a MessageProcessing class within the web app doesn't help. But your answer gave me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your data entities in your project if they are POCOs. Otherwise I would create separate models as you have done. But do keep them in a separate assembly (not in the DataAccess project)

imho people overuse layers. Most applications do not need a lot of layers. My current client had a architecture like yours for all their applications. The problem was that only the data access layer and the presentation layer had logic in them, all other layers just took data from the lower layer,  transformed it, and sent it to the layer above.

The first thing I did was to tell them to scrap all layers and instead use something like this (requires a IoC container):

- Core (Contains business rules and dataaccess through an orm)
- Specification (Seperated interface pattern. Contains service interfaces and models)
- User interface (might be a webservice, winforms, webapp)

That works for most application. If you find that *Core* grows and becomes too large too handle you can split it up without affecting any of the user interfaces.

You are already using an ORM and have you thought about using a validation block (FluentValidation or DataAnnotations) for validation? Makes it easy to validate your models in all layers.

Answer (score 0):

Classes that are used in many layers get me worried.

Especially when they are also tied to the data- model/base/layer.

As soon as there is a change in these classes you could run into re-coding in all layers. In other words you are missing the helpful effect of abstraction.

That said, maintaining transformation code (from layer to layer) is not much fun either but in general less work.

An in between solution might be the use of interfaces/roles: Define for each layer the interface/role that an object should play and use that interface to be passed to the layer. A (shared) class should then implement a role (or many of them). This will provide a more loosely coupled system.

I learned a lot from [this neat lecture about DCI (Data, Collaborations, and Interactions)](http://oredev.org/videos/dci--re-thinking-the-foundations-of-oo)